# IONIC 2 ion-content overlaps ion-header in Android

Tags: ionic2

ion-tabs and ion-content overlaps ion-header when i load an image in the header, it only happens the first time i'm visiting the page, after that it loads well.
**this is the component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {
public image: string;
appName = 'Ionic App';
constructor(public navController: NavController) { }
ionViewDidLoad(){
this.image = "https://source.unsplash.com/640x300/?technology"
}
}
```

Here is the html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title></ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<img class="cabecera" [src]="image" width="100%">
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding class="contenido">
Welcome to this <ion-icon name="ionic"></ion-icon> <b>Ionic 2 app</b>.
</ion-content>
```

Its posible to view an example in this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/CpBXmn?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are only loading the image (in the ionViewDidLoad function) after the rest of the content is loaded. After loading the image you need to resize the content, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7706#issuecomment-239721782).

Add `ViewChild` and `Content` to your imports from `@angular/core` and `ionic-angular`, respectively:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Use `@ViewChild` to select the class for the `ion-content` component:

```
// ...
export class HomePage {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
    // ...
```

Then, once the image is loaded, call the resize method on `content`:

```
this.content.resize();
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)